# Solve for variable

Tags: matlab, variables, equation

I tried to solve the equation below for x.

```
S = solve('1./sqrt(x-1)','x');
```

Somehow that does not work at all. I also tried the method with `syms x`

Is there an easy way to approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Error message:

```
Warning: Support of strings that are not valid variable names or define a
number will be removed in a future release. To create symbolic
expressions, first create symbolic variables and then use operations on
them. 
> In sym>convertExpression (line 1536)
  In sym>convertChar (line 1441)
  In sym>tomupad (line 1198)
  In sym (line 177)
  In solve>getEqns (line 405)
  In solve (line 225) 
Error using symengine
Invalid input. 'expression' is expected.

Error in sym>convertExpression (line 1543)
s = mupadmex({x});

Error in sym>convertChar (line 1441)
    s = convertExpression(x);

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1198)
        S = convertChar(x);

Error in sym (line 177)
                S.s = tomupad(x);

Error in solve>getEqns (line 405)
        a = sym(a);

Error in solve (line 225)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});
```

Comment: Please do not make vague statements and expect a specific answer. Say what you did and what you got in return.

Comment: I think it is obvious. If I have y = 1+x simply get my x on one site -> x = y-1

Comment: What errors are you getting? Your math is fine. I was asking from a coding point of view, since you know, this is a coding Q&A site.

Comment: Ah,sorry for the misunderstanding. It is quite long: Error using symengine
Invalid input. 'expression' is expected.

Error in sym>convertExpression (line 1543)
s = mupadmex({x});

Error in sym>convertChar (line 1441)
    s = convertExpression(x);

Error in sym>tomupad (line 1198)
        S = convertChar(x);

Error in sym (line 177)
                S.s = tomupad(x);

Error in solve>getEqns (line 405)
        a = sym(a);

Error in solve (line 225)
[eqns,vars,options] = getEqns(varargin{:});

Comment: That's fine. Sorry for being an ass about it. Could you post that in the question itself?

Comment: No problem mate. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper way of calling `solve`:

```
syms x real
S = solve((x-1)^-0.5 == 0, x);
```

as recommended here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html

Or, even simpler:

```
x = 1;   % :-)
```

Comment: Thanks first of all. How can I see how the equation looks if x is on one side?!

Comment: @Detox I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "how can I see how the equation looks like"? I'm asking because the equation will stay the same; is the solution that changes value. By the way, as a general guideline here: if you have supplemental questions, you should add them to your original post, so everybody can see them.

Comment: Already solved my problem. See below. With my question I meant how I can see the output of my rearranged formula.

Answer (score -1):

```
syms x y

solve('y = 1/(x-1)',x)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. It's just code. Please delete this or expand it into a [proper answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also, you're still using strings to specify your equation, which is a deprecated notation (as the warning indicates).

Comment: I do not know how to improve this answer. It is the solution to my problem that I wanted to isolate x in the given equation and put it on one side.